# Significance of k-mer length in COVID-19 sequence analysis?

Tags: python, sequence-analysis, covid-19, k-mer, sars-cov-2

I'm getting started in biology and bioinformatics with sequencing the SARS-Cov-2 or Coronavirus genome.  I'm interested in this code which identifies k-mers in the genome:

```
from skbio import DNA 
DNA(str(seq.seq)).kmer_frequencies(5)
kmers = DNA(str(seq1.seq)).kmer_frequencies(5)
kmers
{'ATTAA': 60, 'TTAAA': 95, 'TAAAG': 64, 'AAAGG': 45, 'AAGGT': 46, 'AGGTT': 51, 'GGTTT': 55, 
'GTTTA': 69, 'TTTAT': 75,...}
```

The author of the code wants to use k-mer breakdowns to vectorize the data for machine learning purposes.  What I'm curious about is why the k-mer in this case is five nucleotides?  What factors should go into my selection of the length of the k-mer for analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5bp produces a high resolution analysis, providing its sufficiently robust.

Its a sliding window of 5 bp wide and 1 bp step length which runs along the length of each genome. They are performing SNP analysis/classification. The original sequence they were examining was,

```
ATTAAAGGTTTAT
```

In any sliding window analysis the window size is arbitary towards the resolution and robustness of the analysis. The author believes that 5bp provides sufficiently robust information for a very high resolution classification/training analysis in their example.

The proof is the `accuracy` of the classification. I assume they have good results from 5bp. In ML the rationale is the general laws of ML (over/under training) and assessed on the test split in the data (probably 20%).

A key reason for the 1bp step is that this is the way ML works, you need a lot of data and by doing 5 bp sliding window at 1 bp step that will generate ~30 000 pieces of data for each sequence. So that's 3 million data points for 100 sequences.

Comment: Would the SNP analysis you mention include a classification algorithm such as principal component analysis?

Comment: Oh sorry thats different, PCA (ML) is a different analysis to the one I had in mind (supervised learning) and is usually performed in conjunction with tSNE @greenpenguin. PCA is judged on its ability to cluster the classification targets into different groups. PCA/tSNE is called unsupervised learning